# Get column data type from table and some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want column data type and if data type is int then show column name and if varchar then show column name with '' in horizontal line alien

I tried something like but don't know how to apply condition:

```
SELECT 
    t.Name 'Data type'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    where object_id = OBJECT_ID('tbl_Check_Sql_Query')
```

Suppose my column has Data type

```
id int 
name varchar 
Email_ID varchar
```

Then i want

```
id,'name','Email_ID'
```

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results if this question is to make any sense.

Comment: is it clear edited my question ???

Comment: What do you mean by *column name with '' in horizontal line alien*?

Comment: suppose my column has Data type
id int
name varchar
Email_ID varchar  then i want id,'name','Email_ID';

Comment: What about other data types? What it should be returned?

Comment: if datetime then return getdate ()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use **[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** system view as

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       CASE DATA_TYPE WHEN 'INT' THEN COLUMN_NAME
                      --WHEN 'VARCHAR' I don't know what you mean by "in horizontal line alien"
       END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
--WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

Or

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR'
                       THEN QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME, '''')
                       ELSE COLUMN_NAME
                  END, ',') Columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
--WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8ad567a1cb4eaa4de1d4cd407d54e567)**

Or

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR' 
                            THEN QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME, '''')
                            ELSE COLUMN_NAME
                       END
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T2
          WHERE T1.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
          FOR XML PATH('')

         ), 1, 1, ''
       ) Columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T1
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

**[2nd Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9c5777fa730d17411df2c8ef05bce144)**

---

*UPDATE:*

Since you're trying to return `GETDATE()` value when the data type is `DATETIME` then

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + CASE DATA_TYPE WHEN 'VARCHAR' 
                                          THEN QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME, '''')
                                      WHEN 'DATETIME'
                                          THEN 'GETDATE()'
                            ELSE COLUMN_NAME
                       END
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T2
          WHERE T1.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
          FOR XML PATH('')

         ), 1, 1, ''
       ) Columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS T1
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: throwing error 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @NitsPatel Added code for other SQL Server versions.

Comment: @NitsPatel How _"its showing only TABLE_NAME"_? Did you check the demos?

Comment: i am using sql server 2012

Comment: now i checked its working but one more thing can i return datetime data type into getdate

Comment: i dont want date value as 2019-11-10 I just want if my data type is datetime then it should be return only getdate()

Comment: Good job sorting out the initial (and changing) requirement and providing the adequate answer...

Comment: You did a good job to help others too @GMB although _"in horizontal line alien"_ is a bit unclear ;)